# Should I answer duplicates, should I vote on them all?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I recently discovered three questions that were arguably duplicates.

1. [What does the pipe operator do in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037429/what-does-the-pipe-operator-do-in-sql)
2. [What does the pipe/veritcal bar character mean in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993532/what-does-the-pipe-veritcal-bar-character-mean-in-tsql/30048501)
3. [What does the pipe do in this T-SQL Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047679/what-does-the-pipe-do-in-this-t-sql-statement/30048152)

I voted to close 2. and 3., marking them as duplicates of the others. Was that right, or should I vote to close all questions as duplicates?

I answered all three with an identical answer. Was that wrong?

My answer on 1. is deleted by the moderator @ChrisF but this is now the only question that is now not marked as a duplicate. Therefore I think, 1. is the only question where my answer shouldn't be deleted. Is that wrong?

What is the correct approach to answering and voting on multiple duplicates?

Comment: Answering duplicates is somewhat discouraged on SO (it was discussed many times already), so you definitely shouldn't answer dupes rather vote to close them all, especially if you answered with identical answer 3 times (!)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I hope I haven't created another duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I voted to close 2. and 3., marking them as duplicates of the others.
>   Was that right, or should I vote to close all questions as duplicates?

This is the right behaviour if 1 isn't a duplicate already.

> I answered all three with an identical answer. Was that wrong?

I'd say yes and no. I have seen a lot of questions before which have been a duplicate, and the answers were kept on it because people might not look on the original question or something vague (I think I've even seen a meta post about this). Answering duplicates is most of the time not the right thing to do.

This however is just 3 times the exact same answer posted on the same moment and all the questions linked to the one where the answer already is. Assuming the other 2 questions weren't closed as duplicates yet, but you knowing they were duplicates yet still answer all of them is not the right behaviour.

> Therefore I think, 1. is the only question where my answer shouldn't
>   be deleted. Is that wrong?

I think this is the right way of thinking since that is not a duplicate.

Comment: hey you answered a dup! LOLOL